# Making a point follow another point

Tags: vector, lua, love2d

I am writing a **very quick** mini game, and I don't have any vector implementation for it. This is what I have:

```
local qx = manx
        local qy = many
        local px = bigenemyx
        local py = bigenemyy
        local vx = qx - px
        local vy = qy - py
        local mag = math.sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2)
        bigenemyx = bigenemyx + mag * speed * dt
        bigenemyy = bigenemyy + mag * speed * dt
```

`bigenemy` needs to follow `man`. `bigenemy` just disappears off the screen. I've rushed the code for this and am (evidently) not experienced with the maths in this, thanks for any help - apologies if I just haven't thought straight, I haven't really stuck to "more speed less haste"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are using 'mag' value in all directions - it is not good. Try

```
    if(mag < 0.0001): mag = 1
    bigenemyx = bigenemyx + (vx/mag) * speed * dt
    bigenemyy = bigenemyy + (vy/mag) * speed * dt
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in the last two lines.  You are moving the enemy in the direction of <1,1> no matter what.  Try:

```
bigenemyx = bigenemyx + vx/mag*speed*dt
bigenemyy = bigenemyy + vy/mag*speed*dt
```

So you are getting the direction from v.